# Actionscript 3 PHP output incorrect XML encoding

Tags: php, xml, encoding, actionscript, moodle

I have two XML files,

This was a copy/paste from the output of a web service call to an LMS (Moodle)
http://clsasset.coastlinelive.com/LTI/XMLFile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imsx_POXEnvelopeResponse xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/lis/oms1p0/pox">
  <imsx_POXHeader>
    <imsx_POXResponseHeaderInfo>
      <imsx_version>V1.0</imsx_version>
      <imsx_messageIdentifier>524041811</imsx_messageIdentifier>
      <imsx_statusInfo>
        <imsx_codeMajor>success</imsx_codeMajor>
        <imsx_severity>status</imsx_severity>
        <imsx_description>Grade replace response</imsx_description>
        <imsx_messageRefIdentifier>526f30b728966</imsx_messageRefIdentifier>
      </imsx_statusInfo>
    </imsx_POXResponseHeaderInfo>
  </imsx_POXHeader>
  <imsx_POXBody>
    <replaceResultResponse/>
  </imsx_POXBody>
</imsx_POXEnvelopeResponse>
```

and this was a sample XML I found randomly on the net, and then renamed some elements to be common with the first one
http://clsasset.coastlinelive.com/LTI/XMLFile2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>

<catalog>
  <imsx_codeMajor id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>
      An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.
    </description>
  </imsx_codeMajor>
  <imsx_codeMajor id="bk102">
    ...
  </imsx_codeMajor>
  ...
</catalog>
```

Here is the AS3 code I used to read these files:

```
var commandURL:String = "http://clsasset.coastlinelive.com/apps/LTI/XMLFile.xml?time=" + Math.random();

//Load XML
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(commandURL));

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded, false, 0, true);
var xmlData:XML;



function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void
{
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = (e.target as URLLoader);
xmlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
xmlData = XML(xmlLoader.data);

trace("LTI Provider Full Data" + xmlData);

var statusXML:XMLList = xmlData.child(0);
trace("LTI Provider Result Data" + xmlData..imsx_codeMajor);

}
```

For some reason, "xmlData..imsx_codeMajor" (or .. any element for that matter) always return empty when loading XMLFile.xml.  However, if I load XMLFile2.xml it returns a nice XMLList object.

For kicks, I retyped the entire XMLFile.xml to XMLFile3.xml, and it loaded and parsed fine too.

This leads me to think that it's an encoding issue.  The problem is that the XML data is printed via PHP using a variable that receives data from a web service, which I have no control of.

The PHP script that spits out the XML was a derivative of the LTI sample code base, and the essential parts of the PHP files are:

```
header ('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
.
.
.
$response = sendOAuthBodyPOST($method, $endpoint, $oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $content_type, $postBody);  //Call LMS with data
echo(utf8_encode($response));  //write the response XML
```

It's supposed to be a platform-agnostic call, so I not supposed to be able to manipulate what's on the other side of the sendOAuthBodyPost call.

How do I fix the output encoding so that Flash would be able to parse it?  I'm new to PHP, so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Another note:  I am able to traverse through the XMLFile.xml structure using xmlData.child(index) but not xmlData.child(name), and any attempt to read any attributes at any nodes always returns empty.

---

*File 3* http://clsasset.coastlinelive.com/LTI/XMLFile3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imsx_POXEnvelopeResponse>
  <imsx_POXHeader>
    <imsx_POXResponseHeaderInfo>
      <imsx_version>V1.0</imsx_version>
      <imsx_messageIdentifier>524041811</imsx_messageIdentifier>
      <imsx_statusInfo>
        <imsx_codeMajor>success</imsx_codeMajor>
        <imsx_severity>status</imsx_severity>
        <imsx_description>Grade replace response</imsx_description>
        <imsx_messageRefIdentifier>526f30b728966</imsx_messageRefIdentifier>
      </imsx_statusInfo>
    </imsx_POXResponseHeaderInfo>
  </imsx_POXHeader>
  <imsx_POXBody>
    <replaceResultResponse />
  </imsx_POXBody>
</imsx_POXEnvelopeResponse>
```

Comment: I guess your question is actionscript related with which I'm not too fluent, however, I can see that XML Namespaces are involved and I somewhat have the feeling those are causing understanding problems. Learn about XML Namespaces, and see how they are supported when you query the document.

Comment: Some background on this project.  It is an LTI Provider project.  The PHP script receives data from Flash Actionscript object, makes a virtual POST to the Learning Management System that loaded it, which returns an XML structure; the PHP script then "echo" the result so that the Flash Object can then parse.  XMLFile.xml is the exact structure that an LTI Consumer result service would return.  Somehow, it can't be parsed by Actionscript.

Comment: It's missing the namespace declaration :) As written, that most likely is your issue and in File 3 the xmlns of File 1 is missing. Compare the root element.

Comment: Hi hakre.  Thanks for pointing out the namespace difference.  It hit the nail right on the head.  Taking out the xmlns reference made the file work.  Back to the keyboard.

Comment: Actually having a namespace there should not impose any problem. Removing is not really trivial with PHP, I only have code-fragments that can do that partially, but as written, you should be able to just use the namespace with the client code, AS3 XML parser should have no issues with namespaces, their parser is XML compatible and Namespaces are part of XML. Same for XML parser in PHP, they can deal with XML Namespaces just fine as well. Instead learn what that xmlns is for and how that works. It's then easy to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for the insights.  I may use PHP to change or corrupt the attribute as a last resort hack.  I agree that it's better to learn to work with it than try to change it.  Thanks again for directing me in the right direction

Comment: Thanks to hakre's input, and a little bit of Googling, I found this article at http://brianmriley.wordpress.com/2008/03/20/getting-around-unknown-namespaces-in-flex-and-as/.  I was able to get it to read the XML by adding \*:: to the beginning of the search element.  basically, "trace("LTI Provider Result Data" + xmlData..imsx_codeMajor);" was changed to "trace("LTI Provider Result Data" + xmlData..\*::imsx_codeMajor);".

Comment: you match any namespace then it sounds like. there you go. It's better to understand what's going on because then you have more choice and power.

Comment: Yes, the script's only interested in the data structure. The wildcard allows it to be more agnostic of the caller.  Thanks again for the help.